# How can I plot my daily cost on Azure OpenAI for a given OpenAI model (and not the sum for all OpenAI models)?

Tags: azure-cost-management

I created several Azure OpenAI resources in my Azure account. I deployed GPT models in each of the Azure OpenAI resources. I access them via the Azure OpenAI Playground.

I can view the cost per day of the sum of all the models deployed in my Azure OpenAI resource:

[image]

I don't  see any model option in the filter or aggregation criteria. I don't see any other pages with cost plot.

How can I plot my daily cost on Azure OpenAI for a given GPT model (and more generally, any OpenAI model)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One has to add a filter, and the trick is that it's called the models are referred to as "part number":

[image]

One may found the model's part number on the cost analysis per model:

[image]